# unable to show google maps on mvc view .cshtml page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor, view

i need to show dynamic longitude and latitude in a google map . im able to show map markers in the html page , but im unable to show in .cshtml page. in console window also there is no error showing.

view page code

```
     @model List<smartpond.Models.AssetTrackerViewModel>
        @{

            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }

            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <style>

                #map {
                    height: 100%;
                }

                html, body {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
            </style>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="map"></div>

            </div>
            @section scripts{

        <script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDci4vYApOxVdKqwlpXSv9h77AcWbNuzmQ&callback=initMap">
        </script>
@section scripts{
    <script>
                function initMap() {
                    var myLatLng = { lat: 22.825261, lng: 86.163366 };//Bharat Seva Ashram
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: myLatLng
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });
            }
    </script>

            }
```

Comment: add you `js` after the map api.

Comment: added as u said still not showing any map.

Comment: while using layout map not displaying, without layout its showing map. may be the issue of document .get elementbyid is not working in while adding layout